# componentDidCatch + window.addEventListener('error', cb) don't behave as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I have a `componentDidCatch` error boundary on my root component, to render a nice error page in case something terrible happens.

But I also have a `window.addEventListener('error', cb)` event handler, in case something even worse happens (outside React).

My issue now is that whenever `componentDidCatch` gets an error, the `window` error handler gets it too, so I always end up with the worst case scenario error handling, rather than the "in-react" one.

Also, it looks like the global error handler is triggered before the React error boundary, so it's not possible to mark an error as "handled" so that I can manually ignore it later.

Here's a CodePen showing my issue:
https://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/MNeYqN

A minimal code example would be:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidCatch(err) {
    console.log('react handled error', err);
  }
  render() {
    return 'foobar';
  }
}

window.addEventListener('error', err => console.log('global error', err));

// on error, I get:
// 'global error', err
// 'react handled error', err
```

On the contrary, with just JavaScript, the local error handler would prevent the error from reaching the window error handler.

https://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/eqzrxO?editors=0010

```js
try {
  throw new Error('error');
} catch (err) {
  alert('scoped error');
}

window.addEventListener('error', () => alert('global error'))
```

Is this expected behavior? Can you think of a way to make it work as I'd like it to?

Comment: Your code typically behaves as it should be! `componentDidCatch` and the `eventListener` you have attached to the _document_ will catch the same errors, and this is what they currently do, they behave as the program expects, but out to your expectations you are not, I was wondering, what is actual scenario that the `eventListener` catches, while `componentDidMount` won't?

Comment: @SultanH. I wouldn't expect the errors handled/caught by `componentDidCatch` to bounce up to `window`, since they are handled in the React component. The React error boundary only catches errors happening in the render phase, while the `window` error handler will catch any other unhandled error (theoretically)

Comment: Great, I had a look to your ErrorBoundry component, I will refactor the problem, which is in there, and let you know what changed in a bit of time.

Comment: Could you register listener in componentDidMount of Boundary component and then you can store handled errors in state?

Comment: @zhuber I really need the most broad error handling logic possible, to catch anything even not related to React. But if you want to post an answer with an example of what you mean it'd be great.

Comment: you can use redux saga for error handling. The generators have a way to bubble up the error and the component can listen to any `error`s (passed as prop) via `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: @codekaizer how is that going to help if my 3rd party jquery plugin breaks the page? Also, I'm not even using Redux

Comment: @FezVrasta - very interesting point you've made here. I think the point of error handling outside of React's lifecycle, as well as inside it is very good. So, +1 for that.  Just kicking around an idea. If you wrap all of your app code (including async etc) in try/catches and throw an object, with a property? Then you can classify/identify them if they are hit by your event listener. Just an idea.

Comment: I figured out that I misunderstood the case you are talking about, sorry for that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like this is just a `development` behaviour. Please take a look at [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12897#issuecomment-410036991)

> In development environment, React uses a trick: caught exceptions are
>   thrown inside a fake DOM event which makes them reported by
>   window.onerror, but then React actually catches them so that they
>   don't propagate up (in case there is an error boundary — otherwise
>   they are rethrown).
>
> In production errors caught by error boundaries stay caught.

I've just tested your example in `production` and `alert` does not show when `error` is thrown in `render` method.

Comment: That's a very useful information! It should be in the docs! (I'll send a PR)

Comment: PR: https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/pull/2168

Comment: This answer explains the unexpected behaviour, but I'm still stuck trying to figure out how to differentiate and handle errors outside of React, since the global error handler will be called for React errors in development.

Comment: I opened an issue to discuss whether there's a way we can make errors behave identically in production and development: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19613